# YT JS iframe API, reload frame with user input value

Tags: javascript, youtube-api, youtube-iframe-api

Trying to get the YT iframe to dynamically change video. Currently using a static video ID and want user to input one via a form. The onPlayerReady function calls another initalize() function, which takes the value of the form data and logs it. The submit button onclick also calls this initalize function. However, when the submit button is clicked, the page refreshes, and the value of the var is gone, and it can't be logged and used to reload the iframe. Any idea of how I'd go about solving this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to pass the input value directly to the function that changes the iframe src, instead of using submit.

Example:

```
var userSrc = document.querySelector("#yourInputId");

if(userSrc.value.length > 1){
   updateSrc(userSrc.value);
}
```

You need to adjust the code if f.e you use an placeholder in your input or anything that would affect the length.

If you still want to use submit, you probaly need to save your input in some way. But i wouldnt recommend it, since its not user friendly to update the page just to change the src.

**Edit**
I put something quick together, that works. This codesnippet will update the src without any pager/iframe refresh. You also may want to load the function after the player has been loaded into the DOM, to do this you can make an condition that checks the player state (this functions comes with the boilerplate from Google's documentation).

```
function loadVid(){
  var videoId = document.querySelector("input[name=vidId").value;

  if(videoId.length > 0){
    player.loadVideoById(videoId);
  } else {
      alert("You need to enter an video id");
    }
}
```

Google has an useful [boilerplate](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference) to get you started if you already havent checked it out.

Comment: Ended up implementing something like this. I replaced the submit button with a faux button which actually just reloads the page, and the input string from the form lingers, and the iframe loads automatically. Very hacky, but so far only solution that works

Comment: Not sure if you need to reload the page. Since its JS you should be able to render the specific component (src) only.

I messed around a little bit with the yt js iframe api and made a solution that doesnt reload the iframe or the page, but only the components needed. Look at my update if you would like to try it.

Comment: Yeah, that ended up being quite hacky. I ended up having to create a wrapper around loadVideoById so I could initialize my custom buttons and bar(for web sockets). It works fine, but it's a bit on the laggy side and I'll have to look into optimising it. Anyway, thank you!